# No Includes directory in Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, esp32, esp-idf

I have just installed Eclipse CTD v2020.6 and ESP-IDF v4.1 and configured it in Windows 10. I can build and flash without any problem. But I don't know why I can't see the Includes directory in Project explore. Is it normal, if so is there any way I can add it there?
Along with that, I have noticed there is not C/C++ build section in Project Properties. :?: I am attaching the screenshots for reference.
If someone can help me with this, I will be grateful.
[[image: Project Properties][1]][image: Project Explorer]

Comment: In the project's _Properties_ dialog, please show the expanded _C/C++ General_ subtree.

Comment: @howlger here https://pasteboard.co/JtjmpM6.jpg

Comment: Maybe some project natures are missing (stored in the `.project` file) or the CDT project configuration is broken (`.cproject`). Is `.cproject` a valid XML file? How did you create the project? Does it look like the same in a new created project?

Comment: @howlgeractually its the blinky example included in the IDF itself..

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I don't know nothing about IDF. Did you check the `.cproject` file whether it's valid XML (click on the filter icon and uncheck _.* resources_ to see the file in the _Project Explorer_)?

Comment: Yep, looks like it..
here's the file contents: https://del.dog/cproject.txt
screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/JtkLv9z.jpg